# Handlebars - custom CSS on table not working

Tags: css, node.js, handlebars.js, puppeteer

I am working on the CSS applied on the table in Handlebars express.

Here's my hbs template to display my table.

```
<div class="table-1">
    <table class="table" cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
           <th class="left">Item No</th>
           <th class="left">Description</th>
           <th class="left">Qty</th>
           <th class="left"> Unit </th>
           <th class="left">Prix</th>
           <th class="left">Discount</th>
           <th class="left">VAT</th>
           <th class="left">Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td> 0000 </td>
           <td> Description </td>
           <td> 0 </td>
           <td> unit </td>
           <td> 0.00 </td>
           <td> 0 % </td>
           <td> 0% </td>
           <td> 0.00 </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td> 0000 </td>
           <td> Description </td>
           <td> 0 </td>
           <td> unit </td>
           <td> 0.00 </td>
           <td> 0 % </td>
           <td> 2.5% </td>
           <td> 0.00 </td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="width: 100%;">
           <td colspan="4"></td>
           <td colspan="3"> Total gross</td>
           <td> 0.00 </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td colspan="4"></td>
           <td colspan="3"> Discount </td>
           <td> 0.00 </td>
     </tr>
           <tr>
           <td colspan="4"></td>
           <td colspan="3"> Total Amt </td>
           <td> 0.00 </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's my css,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .table-1 .left {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .table-1 .table td,
        .table-1 .table th {
            border: none;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        .table-1 tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
        }

        .table-1 th,
        .table-1 tr:last-child {
            background-color: #16e0bb;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        .table-1 tr:last-child>td {
            font-weight: 700 !important;
        }
   </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>

</html>
```

Issue: the CSS is not applied correctly when rendering the PDF template using Handlebars express.  Even inline css is not working especially **when using HEX color codes**.

It seems, that background-color css does not work at all. What other way is there to apply background-color css on the table? To render the pdf, I'm using Handlebars express, puppeteer and NodeJS.

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Actual Output:

[image: Actual Output]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake.. thank you

Comment: I can get the correct result by your code. What's the problem now? You can use Developer Tools (Press F12) to indicate the CSS/JS issue.

Comment: No, actually, when rendering the pdf using Handlebars, the pdf is being generated with the table but without the desired css.. 
[header/last row should be green and text should be white + the striped rows]..

Comment: It seems, that background-color css does not work at all.. Can you please advise what other way to apply background-color css on the table?  To render the pdf, i'm using NodeJS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to fix the issue above.

Solution: should include 'printBackground: true' in PDF options before generating the PDF from HTML with Puppeteer and NodeJS.

Thank you